# Why does Java's XPath evaluator require a custom prefix for an anonymous namespace while querying OpenXML files?

Tags: java, excel, kotlin, xpath, openxml

I'm trying understand how XPath evaluation works for OpenXML files and specifically Excel in the following snippet (for brevity I removed irrelevant nodes):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<workbook xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="x15 xr xr6 xr10 xr2"
    xmlns:x15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2010/11/main"
    xmlns:xr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2014/revision"
    xmlns:xr6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision6"
    xmlns:xr10="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2016/revision10"
    xmlns:xr2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2015/revision2">
    <!-- [..] -->
    <sheets>
        <sheet name="Sheet-One" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1" />
        <sheet name="Sheet-Two" sheetId="3" r:id="rId2" />
        <sheet name="Sheet-Three" sheetId="4" r:id="rId3" />        
    </sheets>
    <!-- [..] -->
</workbook>
```

When I query this XML with an XPath without a custom previx (and without `NamespeceContext` and disabled line `xp.namespaceContext = nc`) it doesn't find the nodes, even though the [XPath-Tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) does.

```
//val xpath = "/workbook/sheets/sheet" // <-- doesn't work
val xpath = "/xx:workbook/xx:sheets/xx:sheet"
val xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath()
val nc = NamespaceContextImpl()
nc.addNamespace("xx", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")
xp.namespaceContext = nc
val sheetNodes = xp.compile(xpath).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET) as NodeList
```

So, I was wondering why is it that one tool works without it and another one doesn't?

I have a theory why the prefix might be requried, but I couldn't confirm, that this is because the `workbook` element specifying the `xmlns` namespace without prefix so it automatically applies to all other nodes, but is the prefix you must use in the Java XPath query actually correct?

Comment: Your theory is correct, default (anonymous) namespace apply to all descendant::self elements. That's why a prefix is needed when attempting to XPath query the document. If the element contains `xmlns=...` (vs  `xmlns:ns=...`) then a default namespace was declared and all elements under it are affected.

Comment: "Where do you learn such tricks?" Judging by the number of questions on StackOverflow from people who have fallen into this trap, most people learn such tricks by getting it wrong, struggling to work out why, and then asking on StackOverflow. A few people, however, learn in the conventional way by reading books and tutorials, or even the language specifications, and even by going on courses.

Answer (score 1):

Note that XPath 2 or 3 with e.g. Saxon-HE (current version is 12.3) allows to bind an "empty" prefix to a namespace URI and then your XPath `/workbook/sheets/sheet` selects three element nodes in your sample:

```
val xpath = "/workbook/sheets/sheet"

val processor = Processor()

val xpathCompiler = processor.newXPathCompiler()

xpathCompiler.declareNamespace("", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main")

val nodes = xpathCompiler.evaluate(xpath, processor.newDocumentBuilder().build(File("sample1.xml")))

println(nodes.size())
```

I have used the Saxon API s9api: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation12/index.html#!xpath-api/s9api-xpath

Comment: That's an interesting alternative and their website looks like it's 90s back again ;-] You write XPath 2 or 3. I didn't know there a different versions. I always thought XPath is XPath. I see I've got some things to catch up with.

Answer (score 0):

Your question reads more like a cry of frustration than a request for information that can be factually answered.

In response to the cry of frustration, it is undoubtedly true that the way namespaces are handled in XPath has proved to be a big usability problem for many users. Unfortunately, although everyone knows this, it's the kind of design mistake that it's very hard to correct subsequently. Later XPath versions have tried to mitigate the problem but sadly, many popular XPath libraries including the one that comes by default with the JDK have never implemented anything beyond XPath 1.0.

Most languages have usability traps like this, and you learn from experience. My own learning style when I tackle a new technology is usually to skim-read a book on the subject, and a good text book usually gives ample warning helping you to avoid such pitfalls. These days, however, many of us have to learn more new technologies than there is room for on our bookshelves, and many people learn by trial and error and by copying and pasting examples. If your learning style is to to learn by trial and error, then I'm afraid you have to accept that you will make errors and some of them won't be obvious.

Comment: I disagree. The question is valid, but I regret askig the last question. I knew people will pick on it :P

Comment: I genuinely had trouble working out what your real question is.

Comment: Yeah, that was stupid. I rephrased the question.

Comment: Interactive tools like the XPath tester often take the namespace bindings from the XML document itself. That's considered bad practice for production applications because you don't want your code to be dependent on the namespace prefixes chosen by the document author.